# The meaning of "in" + noun

Tags: grammar

**In** hindsight, it would have been better to wait.

He spoke **in** opposition to the new law.

Comment: In many if not *most* contexts, it's not easy to assign "meaning" to any given use of a preposition in English. Mainly, they're just meaningless "function words" (as opposed to "content words" that ***do*** have meaning). They're really just the "syntactic glue" that's required between content words in valid utterances. But you might say in your first example, ***in*** means ***with, using, from the perspective of***. And in the second case (where the whole sentence means *He spoke **opposing** the new law*) you could say ***in*** "means" ***from a position of***, if that helps.

Comment: In opposition to st,here, refers to "**expressing opposition to the new law**"

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary has that "in" can be "used to indicate limit, qualification, condition, or circumstance". and gives the particular definition

> 3.4 Pertaining to; with regard to.

The limit or qualification for the statement "I would have been better to wait" is that it is made with hindsight. His condition in relation to the new law is one of opposition.

The matter of which prepositions go with which situations is complex, and often doesn't translate in a  one-to-one way with words from other languages. So developing a feel for the use of prepositions is important.